# c# xml serialization grouping elements in subnodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I would like to serialize some class fields into a group (a subnode element).
For instance:

```
[XmlRoot("person", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement("male")]
    public bool Male { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("street")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

This will create the following XML:

```
<person>
 <male>true</male>
 <street>Some street</street>
 <city>City</city>
</person>
```

But I would like to group (for instance street and city into a subelement), without making an extra subclass holding this two properties.

```
 <person>
     <male>true</male>
     <address>
       <street>Some street</street>
       <city>City</city>
     </address>
 </person>
```

Comment: Why? Just to confuse the deserializer?

Comment: I need to create a custom XML output, which doesn't fit my class structure entirely. The XML will never be deserialized so it's fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize 'by hand', ie write to an XDocument (or even an XmlWriter).

That gives you total control over the format. Using a serializer means you give up (most of) that control.

Comment: Or implement IXmlSerializable on the Person class.